# How to select vehicle counts group by region using postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am new to postgres.

My postgres table name is Vehicle consisting of following columns

```
1.ID
2.name
3. wheel (2,3,4,6,8) // two wheeleer,4 whellers
4. region ('hyderabad','mumbai','delhi',...)
5. polluted ('yes','no')
```

My query is how to select count of 4 wheeler vehicles which are polluted group by regions

Expected Output

```
hyderabad -> 4 
mumbai -> 3
delhi -> 8,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should have a `regions` table somewhere which contains all regions.  Assuming this, you could write the following query:

```
SELECT
    r.region,
    COALESCE(v.cnt, 0) AS count
FROM regions r
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT region, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM Vehicle
    WHERE wheel = 4 AND polluted = 'yes'
    GROUP BY region
) v
    ON r.region = v.region;
```

If you only have a `Vehicle` table, which is bad database design, then we can try the following query:

```
SELECT
    region,
    SUM(CASE WHEN wheel = 4 AND polluted = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count
FROM Vehicle
GROUP BY region;
```

This is inefficient, but at least it would let you report every region even if it has no matching records.

Comment: But then how do you even know that every region is being represented in your answer?

Comment: i know i have to select from regions then using joins i have to count particular regions count

Comment: but idont know exact query